# vector method push_all is not found for a custom struct

Tags: rust

So in this simple example

```
#![feature(collections)]

struct User {
    reference: String,
    email: String
}

fn main() {

    let rows = vec![
        vec!["abcd".to_string(), "test@test.com".to_string()],
        vec!["efgh".to_string(), "test1@test.com".to_string()],
        vec!["wfee".to_string(), "test2@test.com".to_string()],
        vec!["rrgr".to_string(), "test3@test.com".to_string()]
    ];
    let mut rows_mut: Vec<Vec<String>> = Vec::new();
    rows_mut.push_all(&rows);

    let mut users_mut: Vec<User> = Vec::new();
    let users = vec![
        User { reference: "ref1".to_string(), email: "test@test.com".to_string() },
        User { reference: "ref2".to_string(), email: "test1@test.com".to_string() }
    ];
    users_mut.push_all(&users);

}
```

I'm getting an error

```
src/main.rs:24:12: 24:28 error: no method named `push_all` found for type `collections::vec::Vec<User>` in the current scope
src/main.rs:24  users_mut.push_all(&users);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Why does it work for `Vec<String>`, but not for `Vec<User>`? Is the only way in this case to iterate and add elements one by one?

Comment: I think it is because `User` doesn't respect clone trait.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at [the definition of `push_all`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.push_all):

```rust
impl<T> Vec<T> where T: Clone {
    fn push_all(&mut self, other: &[T]);
}
```

> Appends all elements in a slice to the `Vec`.
>
> Iterates over the slice `other`, **clones each element**, and then appends it to this `Vec`. The `other` vector is traversed in-order.

(Emphasis mine.)

Your type must implement `Clone` because it clones each value. `String` does; `User` doesn’t. You can add `#[derive(Clone)]` to it.

If you are willing to consume the source vector, you should use `x.extend(y.into_iter())` which avoids needing to clone the values.

Of course, for this trivial case if it’s purely the difference in `mut`ness, just add the `mut` in the initial pattern (if it’s a function argument this works too, the bit before the colon in each argument is a pattern, like with `let`, so `fn foo(mut x: Vec<T>) { … }` works fine and is equivalent to `fn foo(x: Vec<T>) { let mut x = x; … }`.)

Answer (score 4):

Because, if you go to the [documentation for `Vec::push_all`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.push_all) and scroll up and little, you'll see this line:

```rust
impl<T: Clone> Vec<T>
```

This means that the following methods are only implemented for `Vec<T>` when `T` implements `Clone`.  In this case, `T` would be `User`, and `User` *does not implement `Clone`*.  Therefore, the method does not exist.

You can solve this by adding `#[derive(Clone)]` before `struct User {...}`.